# Qt How to display a list of C++ QQuickPaintedItem in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a list of C++ objects derived from QQuickPaintedItem. Each object is capable of painting itself. How do I display this list of objects in QML? I wanted to use Repeater, but if I set the model of the Repeater to the list, what do I put as delegate since the objects can paint themselves?

RandomObject.h:

```
class RandomObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Paintable*> paintable_list READ paintableList NOTIFY paintableListChanged)
public:
    RandomObject(QObject* parent=nullptr);
    QList<Paintable*> paintableList();
signals:
    void paintableListChanged();
}
```

paintable.h:

```
class Paintable : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Paintable(QQuickPaintedItem* parent=nullptr);
protected:
    paint(QPainter* painter);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (qEnvironmentVariableIsEmpty("QTGLESSTREAM_DISPLAY")) {
        qputenv("QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH", QByteArray("213"));
        qputenv("QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT", QByteArray("120"));

        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    }

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);
    RandomObject random;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("RandomObject", &random);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Repeater
    {
        model: RandomObject.paintable_list
        delegate: //what to specify here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `delegate` is Component, i.e. not an item instance but a declaration of the item, a template. The Repeater instantiates these items according to the model data. The model should provide data to instantiate an item, not the instances itself. Your concept is close to [ObjectModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#object-model) when you need no delegate. Check [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) example for more info

Comment: I tried ObjectModel. I appended each instance of Paintable to an ObjectModel and then set the ObjectModel as the model for Repeater, but still nothing appear.

Comment: You probably need no Repeater. I don't really know how and for what do you want to show your items but if your items are already instantiated all you need is assign them to some parent and maybe set size. You probably have to register your `Paintable` type. I also would replace `QList` with `QVariantList` for better compatibility.

Comment: Please provide a complete example.